# After update chrome won't open desktop is read only

Tags: updates, filesystem, 15.10

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 and just did a software update via the software update manager. Now chrome will not open neither will Firefox and if I try to copy anything to my desktop I get an error message:

```
read only destination
```

The software update manager isn't opening either. In fact it is the only unresponsive thing in system settings.

Also I just tried to system restore and I received an error stating:

```
restore error, error creating directory: read only file system.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information by [edit]ing your question and telling us: what version of Ubuntu you're running? Where you get the error message?

Comment: I'm on 14.04, so cannot help you any further. I've added a few extra tags so people running the same OS version as you might give you further help.  Also [edit] your answer, and include more details (like how do you restore, what is the exact error message when copying to your desktop, ... iow: help us to help you!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm too frustrated with this and not really receiving a lot of support, sorry for wasting your time im just going to buy a copy of windows tomorrow..